# When reading cell data from excel in java it returns decimal value

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to read values from the excel file. The value in field is **7430031259**, I used the code
`item_code = cell.toString();` to get the value, but the output is like this **7.430031259E9**.
How to solve this?

Comment: Does [`cell.getNumericCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue--) work? **Note**, it returns a `double`... If that doesn't work, use a `BigDecimal` for parsing the value returned by `cell.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you this one works. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: add the ``BigDecimal `` function too in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best possibility of getting a cell value in apache poi is to use the methods that are meant for this purpose (`toString()` of a cell isn't).

That means you should directly receive a numeric cell value if you are expecting it:

```
double numericValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

should do what you are trying to achieve.

Check the [the JavaDocs of `XSSFCell`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue--) for more useful methods.

For the case you still want to use `cell.toString()` with a `String` representation of a numeric value in scientific / exponential notation, you can use a `BigDecimal` as an intermediate result:

```
BigDecimal bdItemCode = new BigDecimal(cell.toString());
// get the double value of it
double dblItemCode = bdItemCode.doubleValue();
// or get a String in plain notation
String strItemCode = bdItemCode.toPlainString();
```